# Agregar una fecha a algo pero datetime.datetime no es iterable

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x

Quiero obtener parejas de fechas durante cual una casa está ocupada. Por eso estoy intentando agregar una fecha a una lista pero datetime.datetime no es iterable.

Lo hizo en un archivo [booking.py](https://github.com/antoinecomp/bookchatbot/blob/master/booking.py):

```
# select all the name room, starting and ending meeting hour and append them to a list
print("cur_select_all: ")
print(cur_select_all)
for i in cur_select_all:
    room_list.append(i[1])
    print("i[2]: ")
    print(i[2])
    starting_hour_list.append(from_pendulum_to_tupple(pendulum.parse(i[2])))
    ending_hour_list.append(from_pendulum_to_tupple(pendulum.parse(i[3])))
```

Los print devuelven:

```
cur_select_all:
CMySQLCursorBuffered: SELECT * FROM reservations
i[2]:
2018-08-08 12:00:00
```

Pero al añadirlos a `starting_hour_list` hay un error:

```
  File "C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Nathalie\18_2_2019\starter-pack-rasa-stack\booking.py", line 42, in is_the_room_available
    starting_hour_list.append(from_pendulum_to_tupple(pendulum.parse(i[2])))
  File "C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Nathalie\18_2_2019\starter-pack-rasa-stack\staenv\lib\site-packages\pendulum\parser.py", line 20, in parse
    return _parse(text, **options)
  File "C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Nathalie\18_2_2019\starter-pack-rasa-stack\staenv\lib\site-packages\pendulum\parser.py", line 36, in _parse
    parsed = base_parse(text, **options)
  File "C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Nathalie\18_2_2019\starter-pack-rasa-stack\staenv\lib\site-packages\pendulum\parsing\__init__.py", line 70, in parse
    return _normalize(_parse(text, **_options), **_options)
  File "C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Nathalie\18_2_2019\starter-pack-rasa-stack\staenv\lib\site-packages\pendulum\parsing\__init__.py", line 111, in _parse
    return _parse_iso8601_interval(text)
  File "C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Nathalie\18_2_2019\starter-pack-rasa-stack\staenv\lib\site-packages\pendulum\parsing\__init__.py", line 211, in _parse_iso8601_interval
    if "/" not in text:
TypeError: argument of type 'datetime.datetime' is not iterable
```

Entonces cómo agregar un datetime a una lista?

## Para reproducir:

El codigo proviene de [un proyecto para un chatbot.](https://github.com/antoinecomp/bookchatbot)

Answer (score 0):

El problema se debe a que la función `pendulum.parse` espera un argumento de tipo `string`, y el que estas pasando actualmente es de tipo `datetime`. Para solucionarlo puedes puedes usar la función `isoformat` que es parte de la clase `datetime`, como se puede ver a continuación:

```py
for i in cur_select_all:
    room_list.append(i[1])

    starting_hour_list.append(from_pendulum_to_tupple(pendulum.parse(i[2].isoformat())))
    ending_hour_list.append(from_pendulum_to_tupple(pendulum.parse(i[3].isoformat())))
```

Para darle un poco más de claridad reestructuré el código separando cada función en una línea:

```py
for i in cur_select_all:
    room_list.append(i[1])

    hour_starting_datetime = i[2]
    hour_ending_datetime = i[3]

    hour_starting_pendulum = pendulum.parse(hour_starting_datetime.isoformat())
    hour_ending_pendulum = pendulum.parse(hour_ending_datetime.isoformat())

    hour_starting_tupple = from_pendulum_to_tupple(hour_starting_pendulum)
    hour_ending_tupple = from_pendulum_to_tupple(hour_ending_pendulum)

    starting_hour_list.append(hour_starting_tupple)
    ending_hour_list.append(hour_ending_tupple)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias. Sin embargo obtengo dos problemas : por una parte hay `None` en `hour_ending_datetime. Por otra parte cuando escribo `tomorrow` en `hour_starting_datetime ` obtengo una fecha que no esta hoy